# node-notifier - is it possible to create notifications with inputs and buttons on Windows 10, like on OS X?

Tags: node-notifier

I've tried `WindowsToaster` constructor to create some notifications with inputs and buttons, like I did with `NotificationCenter` on OS X, but while on OS X notifications do have buttons and inputs, on Windows 10 notifications have just `title`, `message` and `icon`.

So the question is - can I create buttons and inputs on Windows 10 by using `node-notifier` ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [this](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/blob/master/example/toaster-with-actions.js) and it worked fine.

some problems that I still have:
After timeout, pressing the buttons will do nothing.

If you add "appName:" then it wont show the buttons for some reason.

Edit: instead of `const notifier = require('../index');` I used this one `const notifier = require('node-notifier');`